# Why this function can't be static in Linux driver

Tags: c, linux, static, linux-kernel

I have some assembly codes encapsulated in a static function of my driver code. My codes is like

```
static int _ARMVAtoPA(void *pvAddr)
{
__asm__ __volatile__(
    /* ; INTERRUPTS_OFF" */
    " mrs            r2, CPSR;\n" /* r2 saves current status */
    "CPSID  iaf;\n" /* Disable interrupts */

    /*In order to handle PAGE OUT scenario, we need do the same operation
      twice. In the first time, if PAGE OUT happens for the input address,
      translation abort will happen and OS will do PAGE IN operation
      Then the second time will succeed.
    */

    "mcr    p15, 0, r0, c7, c8, 0;\n "
    /*  ; get VA = <Rn> and run nonsecure translation
        ; with nonsecure privileged read permission.
        ; if the selected translation table has privileged
        ; read permission, the PA is loaded in the PA
        ; Register, otherwise abort information is loaded
        ; in the PA Register.
    */

    /* read in <Rd> the PA value */
     "mrc    p15, 0, r1, c7, c4, 0;\n"
    /* get VA = <Rn> and run nonsecure translation */
    " mcr    p15, 0, r0, c7, c8, 0;\n"

    /*  ; with nonsecure privileged read permission.
        ; if the selected translation table has privileged
        ; read permission, the PA is loaded in the PA
        ; Register, otherwise abort information is loaded
        ; in the PA Register.
    */
    "mrc    p15, 0, r0, c7, c4, 0;\n" /* read in <Rd> the PA value */

    /* restore INTERRUPTS_ON/OFF status*/
    "msr            cpsr, r2;\n" /* re-enable interrupts */

    "tst    r0, #0x1;\n"
    "ldr    r2, =0xffffffff;\n"

    /* if error happens,return INVALID_PHYSICAL_ADDRESS */
    "movne   r0, r2;\n"
    "biceq  r0, r0, #0xff;\n"
    "biceq  r0, r0, #0xf00;" /* if ok, clear the flag bits */
);
}

static unsigned long CpuUmAddrToCpuPAddr(void *pvCpuUmAddr)
{
    int phyAdrs;
    int mask = 0xFFF;  /* low 12bit */
    int offset = (int)pvCpuUmAddr & mask;
    int phyAdrsReg = _ARMVAtoPA((void *)pvCpuUmAddr);

    if (INVALID_PHYSICAL_ADDRESS != phyAdrsReg)
        phyAdrs = (phyAdrsReg & (~mask)) + offset;
    else
        phyAdrs = INVALID_PHYSICAL_ADDRESS;

    return phyAdrs;
}
```

As you can see, I tried to convert a virtual address which from user space to physical address. I'm porting this codes from another project, except I modify the `_ARMVAtoPA` function to static function.

When I'm using `static int _ARMVAtoPA(void *pvAddr)`:

- this convert function (which with bunch of assembly codes in it) is always return **fffffff**, error case for sure.

When I'm using `int _ARMVAtoPA(void *pvAddr)`:

- this convert function would working fine.

Can anyone explain to me, why results are vary when I use static and non-static function.

Thanks

Comment: You may examing resulted (assembler) core of your function in both cases and compare them. Probably, prologue or epilog are differs.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I did this exame. Assembler codes return different vaule.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ASM code doesn't define which register holds the function argument `pvAddr` and which register holds the return value. It just *assumes* the compiler follows mips ABI.

But if the function is inlined (where probably `static` does), the register allocation may change, so the asm code can be totally wrong.

In order to fix the problem, you should use gcc extension to assign registers for function arguments and return value. And also declare which registers it will use w/o restore, so the compiler can restore registers after the call in case the function is inlined.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is insightful.

Comment: the static modifier, in C, for a function, just means that function cannot be accessed from some external file.  It does not force inline'ing.

Comment: @user3629249 Yes you're right, but `inline` is also a compiler optimization behavior. Thanks